# How to divide an array of numbers by another array of numbers

Tags: javascript

Hi guys can someone please help me with some code, so i have two arrays a and b i want to divide a by b. Here is my arrays var a = [
  "14",
  "8",
  "3",
  "5"
];

Var b = [
  "44",
  "16",
  "30",
  "11"
];

So i want my result to be an array. Please can someone help me

Comment: _divide a by b_ - what should be the output? what have you tried? what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` for this

```js
var a = [ "14", "8", "3", "5" ];
var b = [ "44", "16", "30", "11" ];

let res = a.map((d, i) => d/b[i])

console.log(res)
```